# CISCO switch console port not RJ45?

Tags: cisco

In all networking videos and tutorials, a Cisco switch console port is a rj45 connector, which then goes through a rollover cable to a rs232 connector that goes to the computer.

On my switch, which is a SF300-24p switch, the console cable is a rs232 port. How would I connect this to my computer for console configuration?

Comment: Do you mean the interface on the switch is not the modular connector, or do you mean the cable is not a modular cable?

Comment: Yea, the console port on the back of the switch is a female connector for a rs232 cable, not RJ-45

Comment: The console interface is a modular connector on the same side of the switch as the switch interfaces. I'm looking at one sitting on my desk, and there is this: [Cisco SF300-24P 24-Port 10/100 PoE Managed Switch with Gigabit Uplinks](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/switches/sf300-24p-24-port-10-100-poe-managed-switch-gigabit-uplinks/model.html). Notice the image.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's a standard straight-through serial cable with a DB-9 connector.  Your computer will have the opposite gender DB-9 connector.

Comment: Good answer, he's trying to say DB-9 (i.e. RS-232 serial). I will add though that nowadays we buy USB adapters to provide the DB-9 interface. They are available in any office supply store.